# How do I add an action to an element that is dynamically created in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic, element

I have a button, when you click this button it dynamically creates a second button. I need to place a click event on to the dynamically created button (second button), which I do, but my click function isn't working.

How can I get my click function to work with dynamically created elements?

Comment: Are you going to show us how you're doing this?

Comment: Please show your code and error message or specific description of not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the jQuery `.live()` function which can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Example:

```
$('button').live('click', function(){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You either need to bind the click event to the second button after it's created. Or use the jQuery Live or Delegate functions.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, **now or in the future**, based on a specific set of root
>   elements.

Post some code if you need any more help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a long while ago... 
Since jQuery v1.7 the correct way to do that is :

```
$(document).on( "click",'.myNewlyCreatedElement', function () {
    // Your action
});
```

Ref : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/8tgNe/4/).

Markup:

```
<button id="create">Create</button>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

Script:

```
var count = 0;
$("#create").click(function(e) {
    var num = count += 1;
    var newButton = $("<button>New " + num + "</button>").click(function() {
        alert("Button " + num + " was clicked.");
    });
    $("#container").append(newButton);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check out jQuery .live()

[jQeru .live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach an event using jqueries live method. It will bind the event to all instances of current and future elements.

```
$('.classname').live('click', function() {
  alert("triggered");
});
```

this way the click event is added to all elements with the classname of classname - even if you insert more elements with the same class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="but1" type="button" value="click"></input>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#but1').click(function(){
    var button = $(document.createElement('input'));
        button.attr('id', 'but2');
        button.val('but2');
        button.attr('type', 'button');
        button.click(function(){alert('hello');});

        $(document.body).append(button);

    });

});
</script>
```